# Installing Ubuntu on an Asus E410M laptop?

Tags: live-usb, asus

Does anyone know if it's possible to install Linux on an Asus E410M laptop?

I've tried with an Ubuntu live USB, but I can't figure out how to get it to boot from USB. There's no bios screen during boot, so I can't even get into a menu to check if USB boot support is enabled.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Home/All-series/ASUS-E410/techspec/ <- Nothing stands out as a potential problem and it certainly boots from USB. Please check the user's manual on how to access the UEFI settings.

Comment: We do not provide hardware support; we can help if you show us an error, what you now ask is too generic so not really answerable.  "There's no bios screen during boot"  That should always be possible since you need to boot from BIOS. On ASUS it generally is the DEL key pressed when the ASUS logo appears. But ... there are also versions that need F2, F8, or ESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be fine with that laptop.

For ASUS, it’s usually f2 to enter the uefi / bios menu. Hold that down whilst you turn the machine on.

If that doesn’t work, other keys that often do this are f10, f12, Del or Esc. If you have the original documentation, it will probably tell you which key to press.

Sounds like you’re planning on booting from usb (‘try Ubuntu’) before attempting installation which is definitely the right thing to do.